# Access VBA: How to move past 'No Current Record' to next Record where 'Item' = 'Item'

Tags: ms-access, vba

How do I move past 'No Current Record' to next Record where 'Item' = 'Item'

Loop comes back around and finds a Sales Order record in rsSO but not in rsInv or the Inventory recordset, creating the "Record not found error." The reason is that once the Inventory is depleted by allocating it to open Sales Orders I then delete the Inventory record for that specific item but there still may me open sales order left for that item. How do I move to the next item in the Open Sales Order rsSO recordset once the Inventory is depleted in rsInv?

It is happening in the following section of code inside the first loop:

```
     Do Until rsInv!Item = rsSO!Item
       If rsInv!Item = rsSO!Item Then
       Exit Do
       Else
       rsInv.MoveNext
       End If
    Loop
```

Entire code:

```
Public Function UpdateInventoryIntl()

Dim rsInv As DAO.Recordset, rsSO As DAO.Recordset, db As DAO.Database
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Dim AllocationQty As Long, SaleOrderRemainder As Long
Set db = CurrentDb

    Set rsInv = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset( _
            "SELECT * FROM [tbl_InventoryAvailForIntl] ORDER BY [Item] DESC,[QOH_IntlAllocation] DESC", _
            dbOpenDynaset)

    Set rsSO = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM [tbl_IntlAllocated] ORDER BY [Item] DESC,[Qty_Open] DESC", _
            dbOpenDynaset)


    Do Until rsSO.RecordCount = 0

             Do Until rsInv!Item = rsSO!Item
               If rsInv!Item = rsSO!Item Then
               Exit Do
               Else
               rsInv.MoveNext
               End If
            Loop


        AllocationQty = IIf(rsSO!Qty_Open > rsInv!QOH_IntlAllocation, rsInv!QOH_IntlAllocation, rsSO!Qty_Open)

        db.Execute ("INSERT INTO tbl_IntlAllocatedResults (Due_Date, Sale_Order_Num, SO_Line, Item, Qty_OpenStart, Location, Lot, QtyAllocated) " & _
        "VALUES (#" & rsSO!Due_Date & "#,'" & rsSO!Sale_Order_Num & "'," & rsSO!SO_Line & ",'" & rsSO!Item & "'," & rsSO!Qty_OpenStart & ",'" & rsInv!Location & "','" & rsInv!Lot & "'," & AllocationQty & ");")

        rsSO.Edit
        rsSO!Qty_Open = rsSO!Qty_Open - AllocationQty
        rsSO.Update

        If rsSO!Qty_Open = 0 Then
        rsSO.Delete
        rsSO.MoveNext
        End If

        rsInv.Edit
        rsInv!QOH_IntlAllocation = rsInv!QOH_IntlAllocation - AllocationQty
        rsInv.Update
        Debug.Print rsInv!QOH_IntlAllocation

        If rsInv!QOH_IntlAllocation = 0 Then
        rsInv.Delete
        rsInv.MoveNext
        End If

    Loop

rsSO.Close
Set rsSO = Nothing
Set qdf = Nothing
rsInv.Close
Set rsInv = Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: Why are you deleting sales records??  One day you may need to audit them.  Why aren't you marking them complete with a flag, so they can be filtered but still audited?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than cycling through the recordset use FindFirst:

```
Dim sCriteria as String

sCriteria = "Item = " & rsSO!Item
rsInv.FindFirst (sCriteria)
If rsInv.NoMatch Then
    ' Do whatever you need to if there is no inventory
Else
    ' Carry on with your code
End If
```

You may get better efficiency picking up the recordset as you need it, depending on the size of recordset.

Don't set your rsInv initially and then instead of your problematic loop use:

```
Set rsInv = Currentdb.OpenRecordset( _
    "SELECT * FROM [tbl_InventoryAvailForIntl] _
        WHERE [Item] = " & rsSO!Item & " ORDER BY [QOH_IntlAllocation] DESC", _
        dbOpenDynaset)
```

You can then test if there are no records:

```
If rsInv.EOF and rsInv.BOF Then
    ' No records, do what is required when no inventory
End If
```